# Apache Sites Available file in Windows

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server

I'm trying to install the WebNotes Framework in Windows 7. The only [installation guide](http://geexhq.com/webnotes/) is focused on the Linux environment. I'm trying to find out the corresponding file names in Windows.

I've found the Hosts file in Windows.

Linux :

```
/etc/hosts
```

Windows equivalent :

```
C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

However I can't the file equivalents of:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
/etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf
```

Any ideas where these files are in a Windows environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Apache is not a part of XAMPP or something similar, then it's config files are located in `conf` directory under Apache's installation root (something like `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf`).

Comment: yep , it's just apache2.2 But in conf folder - i've opened every file - no one is similiar to 'default' file in Linux :(

Comment: Main Apache config file is `httpd.conf`. You can have as much config files as you need (i.e. when you need to change some options with a script, it's better to put them in separate file) and include them in `httpd.conf`. But for Apache there is no matter in which _file_ you set these options. So, you simply can edit `httpd.conf` and set required options per server or per vhost, as you need